# Take picture from BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, asynchronous, broadcastreceiver, android-camera

I read from the developer guide:

> A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.
>
> This has important repercussions to what you can do in an onReceive(Context, Intent) implementation: anything that requires asynchronous operation is not available, because you will need to return from the function to handle the asynchronous operation, but at that point the BroadcastReceiver is no longer active and thus the system is free to kill its process before the asynchronous operation completes.

From by `BroadcastReceiver` I manage to catch the intent I am interessed in, and in response I want my app to take a picture: but in the above-written explanation, I read that

> anything that requires asynchronous operation is not available

and I may even succeed in taking a picture, but maybe `onReceive` has already returned.
My question is: what is the best practice to take a picture from a `BroadcastReceiver`?

Comment: 1. what do you mean by "take a picture" 2. start some kind of "wakeful service"  from onRecive and "take a picture" from it (or use WakefulBroadcastReceiver from compat library)

Comment: Sorry, I'll be more specific: by "take a picture" I mean that my app should make a photo automatically, without waiting for the user to push the button to take a picture.

Comment: That's what you understood correctly, just start your service of taking picture, all you need to take care of is the releasing and initialing camera source at right time

Comment: Sorry if I insist, but I don't fully understand your answer: should I start a `Service`? Or a thread on which the `onReceive` method will wait the task to be complete?